# Tomcat 7 clears edits made to context.xml on startup

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

This is probably a very n00b question since this is the first time I'm using Tomcat. I'm trying to specify a JDNI resource in the /conf/context.xml file. But every time I start up the server and have a look at the file. Everything I edited in the file has disappeared and the file reverted back the way it looked at the initial default installation of Tomcat.

Note that I do have the server shutdown when I do these edits.. Why is this happening?

Comment: What operating system?  Linux or Windows?  If Linux what flavor?

Comment: This is in Windows 8 64bit.. I have noticed though that this only happens when I start my server up through my IDE (Eclipse). Starting the server up through the terminal (startup.bat) . The file doesn't get cleared.

Comment: How exactly are you starting it from Eclipse?  You should probably be using the bat files to start and stop the server always.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on Eclipse then there should be a folder called `Servers` in your workspace. When you start your server for the first time, it copies over the tomcat conf files into this eclipse project. So no matter if you change your actual context.xml from outside, eclipse will override it with what is stored in the 'Servers' folder.

If you still need the eclipse to take control of your tomcat installation directory, you need to primarily update this file from within the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Tomcat server configuration in Eclipse by double-clicking on it in the Servers view. There you should find a section for setting up how the Tomcat installation is used. Eclipse may be be taking over the installation. Try using the Eclipse workspace metadata option for server location.